# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null error while uploading image in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am developing a project in laravel 5.3 where I have to create a 1 field form to change logo of website my form look like this.

[image]

I do not need to save path in database. I just need to upload file in \public\images\ with name logo and only png files are allowed. so it will be `\public\images\logo.png`

following is the form code.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
    <img src="/images/{{ Session::get('path') }}">
    @endif


    <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border text-center">
            <h3 class="box-title">Basic Info</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/') }}/admin/change-site-logo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <div class="box-body">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="logo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Logo</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="logo" name="logo" placeholder="Logo Image">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="logo" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <img style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" src="https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

</div>
```

this is Route `Route::post('/admin/change-site-logo', 'adminController@logo_change');`

and controller is as following

```
class adminController extends Controller
{

    public function logo_change(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'logo' = > 'required|image|mimes:png|max:2048',
        ]);

        $imageName = 'logo.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

        return back()
            ->with('success', 'Image Uploaded Successfully.')
            ->with('in path', $imageName);
    }
}
```

I am writing first time this kind of code so dont know what to fix. I just know that the error is `Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null`

Comment: I guess image was not uploaded for some reason. So `$request->image` is null

Comment: okay but I am here to get solution.

Comment: Look at the logs on why image was not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$request->image
```

to

```
$request->logo
```

on the line you create `$imageName`.